# How do I get more information when clicking on an item in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, http, phpmyadmin

I working with PHP for the first time. I got some items loaded on my page and when I click on it I want to show more information. This is my connection database code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "webshop";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM items";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();


?>
```

The tables in the database are:

```
Id, name, prijs, cat
```

The connection is working fine and I can retrieve the items with the following code:

```
if($selected_val == "Vrouwen"){
   echo'<section class="products">';
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($row['cat'] == 'vrouwen') {

    $catvrouwen = $row['cat'];
    echo "<div class='product-card'><button id='myBtn'><div class='product-image'><a href='index.php?id=" . $row['id'] . " '><img src='image/1.jpg'></a></div><h5>" . $row['name'] . '</h5><h6>' . '€' . $row['prijs'] . "</h6></button></div>";
    }
    $id = $row['id']; 
    $img = $row['img']; 
    $name = $row['name'];
    $prijs = $row['prijs'];

        echo $_POST['name'];
    }

    $result->close();

}

    echo'</section>';
}

}
```

This code is working fine and when I click on the item I want to see more information about it. This is the code I wrote:

```
if ($id = $_GET['id']) {
echo $id; 
echo '<div class="info2"><div class="info-view">';
echo "<button id='myBtn'><div class='product-image'><a href=''><img src='image/1.jpg'></a></div><h5>"; 
echo $name;
echo "</h5><h6>€";
echo $prijs; 
echo "</h6></button></div>";
echo '</div></div>';
}
```

I can see only **$id** but **$prijs** and **$name** is not showing. 
Can someone help me to show this attributes? 
Kind regards

Comment: You're not making it very clear how this code fits together. I see no mention of `$_GET["id"]` in your database code.

Comment: it get the id from my url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are having this code on a new page. Do this

```
 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if (isset($row['id'])) {
    echo $row['id']; 
    echo '<div class="info2"><div class="info-view">';
    echo "<button id='myBtn'><div class='product-image'><a href=''><img src='image/1.jpg'></a></div><h5>"; 
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</h5><h6>€";
    echo $row['prijs']; 
    echo "</h6></button></div>";
    echo '</div></div>';
    }
    }
```